# Adding an ECS instance in AWS - where to set the cluster name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a cluster "my-cluster"

If I try and add an ECS instance, there are non available. However, if I create a cluster "default", then I have an instance available.

I have deleted the file /var/lib/ecs/data/ecs_agent_data.json as suggested here:

[Why can't my ECS service register available EC2 instances with my ELB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036600/why-cant-my-ecs-service-register-available-ec2-instances-with-my-elb)

Where can I change my instance/load balancer to allow me to use an EC2 instance in "my-cluster" rather than having to use the "default" cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [ECS Agent Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html) docs:

> If you are manually starting the Amazon ECS container agent (for non-Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs), you can use these environment variables in the docker run command that you use to start the agent with the syntax --env=VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE. For sensitive information, such as authentication credentials for private repositories, you should store your agent environment variables in a file and pass them all at once with the --env-file path_to_env_file option.

One of the environment variables in the list is `ECS_CLUSTER`. So start the agent like this:

```
docker run -e ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster ...
```

If you're using the ECS-optimized AMI you can use [an alternative approach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#ecs-config-s3) as well.