# How to connect AWS ECS Service to database in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a SQL Server database running on Windows Server EC2 instance. I also have Web API (ASP.NET Core WebAPI) deployed as a Service in ECS cluster (Fargate launch type).

What connection string should I use to access this database from my web API?

Right now I'm trying:

> data source=NAME_OF_THE_EC2_INSTANCE;initial
>   catalog=DATABASE_NAME;User
>   Id=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=10;

But it doesn't work. The error returned suggests that the app doesn't even see the database at all.

Comment: Have you verified the security groups associated with the Tasks and the EC2 instance which hosts the Database.

Comment: also check that the windows firewall lets traffic through for sql server ports 1433 and 1434.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden why port 1434?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'll need to use a NAT instance/Gateway
This will enable connectivity between your Fargate instance and EC2 instance where DB is installed.

Another [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036600/why-cant-my-ecs-service-register-available-ec2-instances-with-my-elb) and also the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_instances.html)

"...Container instances need external network access to communicate with the Amazon ECS service endpoint, so if your container instances are running in a private VPC, they need a network address translation (NAT) instance to provide this access. For more information, see NAT Instances in the Amazon VPC User Guide."